# File for sys.path.append statement

Tags: python

I have a project folder with `__init__.py` under each directory. In some of the python files, I am doing the following to import modules from another script in my project.

```
import re
import csv
import sys

from os import path

ROOT_DIR = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname('__file__')))
# print(ROOT_DIR)
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)

from source.constants import IP
```

My question where should this statement go:

```
ROOT_DIR = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname('__file__')))
    # print(ROOT_DIR)
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)
```

Folder Structure:

```
MyProject/
|- __init__.py
|- source/
    |- __init__.py
    |- trie.py
    |- constants.py
|- data/
    |- __init__.py
    |- data.csv
|- utilities/
    |- __init__.py
    |- importer/
        |- __init__.py
        |- init_nodes.py
```

Comment: Nowhere. Make it a proper module.

Comment: I have added the folder structure. init_nodes.py in utilities->importer folder imports from constants in source folder. How should I do it if not by sys.append

Answer (score 0):

That statement should go in the invoke script of your project, and each module you import should be imported from the root directory of your project.

For example:

```
Project
  script.py
  package
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    sub_package1
      __init__.py
      foo1.py
```

In `script.py`

```
sys.path.append(path_to_project)
```

Import `foo1.py` in `foo.py`

```
from package.sub_package1 import foo1
```

Import `foo.py` in `foo1.py`

```
from package import foo
```

Also, the question was edited but make sure your init files are named `__init__.py` and not `init.py`.